# Evaluate flux integral $\iint\limits_S F ⋅n dS $ over $x^2+y^2+z^2=4$ in first octant

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals

So the question asks to evaluate$\iint\limits_S F ⋅n dS $ where $F(x,y,z)=<1,1,1>$ and S is the part of the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=4$ in the first octant ($n$ is the unit outward normal vector to the surface $S$).

I tried to use the divergence theorem but div$F$ is 0 .

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Its not a problem, the answer is 0.

Comment: so using the divergence theorem is correct which leads to 0?

Comment: The divergence theorem requires that the surface is closed.  If your surface is only the section of the sphere, using the divergence theorem is wrong.

Comment: @63677 even if I use the divergence theorem on the entire sphere to divide it by 8 at the end, I get 0

Comment: 63677 is correct. I misread problem statement. The divergence theorem cant be used if the surface is not closed.

Comment: The answer will be nonzero for sure. Do you inow how to compute surface integrals by hand?

Comment: so it's not possible to find the surface integral of the whole sphere and divide it by 8?

Comment: Definitely not, because that surface integration equals 0. There are positive and negative contributions to the overall result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note $n=(\frac x2, \frac y2,\frac z2)$ and $F\cdot n = \frac12 (x+y+z)$. Then, the integral becomes,

$$I = \iint\limits_S F ⋅n dS = \frac12\iint\limits_S (x+y+z)dS = \frac32\iint\limits_S zdS $$

where the symmetry with respect to $x$, $y$ and $z$ is recognized in the last step. In spherical coordinates with $r=2$,

$$I =\frac32 \int_0^{\pi/2}\int_0^{\pi/2} r^3\cos\theta \sin\theta d\theta d\phi=3\pi$$

Comment: how did you get $n$?

Comment: @ph-quiett - $n = (f_x',f_y',f_z')$, normalized, where $f = x^2+y^2+z^2-4$.